# Changing variables in Greens theorem

Tags: integration

So we where learning yesterday about greens theorem and my teacher solved this integral for us

$$   \oint{(x^3-2y+{x^2}Sin({x^3}+{y^3}))dx} + (2xy+{y^2}Sin({x^3}+{y^3}))dy  $$
$$   \partial D: x^2+y^2=2x$$

By using greens theorem ,$$ x=r Cos(\theta) $$ and $$ y=r Sin(\theta) $$

the integral becomes

$$
\int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2}d{\theta}\int^{2Cos(\theta)}_{0}(2rSin(\theta)+2)rdr
$$

I understand how the integral became this way but don't know how he came up with $$\pi/2,-\pi/2,2Cos{\theta},0$$ as boundries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting $x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$ in
$$x^2+y^2=2x,$$
we have
$$r^2=2r\cos\theta$$
and $x^2+y^2=2x$ is in the right half-plane ($x\ge 0$) and is tangent to the vertical axis ($x=0$):
[image]

Comment: could you explain answer further please, thanks.

Comment: @asdfgg, I will add a drawing later.

Comment: ok, I'll wait your help.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again Martín, but do you know where I could find some problems like this one on the internet to solve, I have an exam and I need to practice, thanks.

Comment: @asdfgg, search "Green theorem"/"Greens theorem"... here.